# aspx localization local resources datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have a ASPX Application which i have started to apply localization to, with the intent to make it possible for the users to switch languages.
an unintended change made it that when users are using the webpage now, their Date time format is being used on the server side. in the past this was not an issue.
Im not sure what the best approach would be to fix this.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.Hours (Username,LogIn,LogOut,TotalHours,Char,Game,Server1,Server2,S1Plat,S2Plat) VALUES (@uname, @in, @out, @totlH, @char, @game, @S1, @S2, @S1Plat, @S2Plat)";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in", DateTime.Now);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out", DateTime.Parse("1/31/1753"));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@char", drop_vet.SelectedValue);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@game", drop_game.SelectedValue);

 if (chk_duties.Checked)
 {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S1", txt_duties.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S2", "Assigned by: " + drop_gm.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S1Plat", "N/A");
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S2Plat", "N/A")
 }
 else
 {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S1", drop_server1.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S2", drop_server2.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S1Plat", drop_platformS1.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S2Plat", drop_platformS2.SelectedValue);

      cmd.CommandText += "; Update dbo.Servers SET LastVisit = @lv where platform = @s1plat and number = @s1Num and Game = @game";
      cmd.CommandText += "; Update dbo.Servers SET LastVisit = @lv where platform = @s2plat and number = @s2Num and Game = @game";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", DateTime.Now);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s1Num", drop_server1.SelectedValue.Split(' ')[0]);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s2Num", drop_server2.SelectedValue.Split(' ')[0]);
 }
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 conn.Close();
```

Currently, it works perfectly fine when used on the server, or when used on a computer that is set in US locale. However when the computer is in the Dutch(for example) locale this function will fail on the DateTime.Parse Saying its in the wrong format.

As a quickfix i reversed my application back to before i started applying localization, currently im also fearing it might use the timezone of the local machine now instead of the server time, i have not been able to verify this yet though. Does anyone have some suggestions for me? Bassicly im trying to have multiple languages on aspx(im using resx files) without changing the rest of the locale stuff

Comment: Upon further testing it appear that in Google chrome it does crash, and in Mozilla Firefox it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by using this instead of the above.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out", DateTime.ParseExact("01/31/1753 00:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```